# plot fig with 6 subplots with 3 variables - python

Tags: python

var = [var1, var2, var3] each of the values in "var" are list of 2, and var1 has the shape (129,135) and other 2 have the shape (201,321). i want to plot the var in a fig with 6 subplots using matplotlib. is the following code correct? what would be the modifications to the code ? i need 3 different colorbar for each row.

```
fs=12           # font size

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(6,8), dpi=300)
titl='H_L '
fig.suptitle(titl,fontsize=fs, weight='normal')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace= 0.4, wspace=0.5)          # gap between the subplots

for h in range (3) :
    for i in range(2) :
        ax = axs[h, i]
        sub_titl = ['H','L' ]
        ax.set_title(sub_titl[i], fontsize=fs, weight= 'bold' )
        ax.background_patch.add_feature(feature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',
                                                name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines', 
                                                scale='50m', 
                                                facecolor='none'))
        gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), 
                      linewidth=1, 
                      color='grey', 
                      alpha=0.3, 
                      linestyle='-', 
                      draw_labels=True)
        gl.top_labels = False
        gl.right_labels = False
        gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
        gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
        gl.xlabel_style = {'size': fs}
        gl.ylabel_style = {'size': fs}

        clist = ['#7f0000','#a50f15','#cb181d','#ef3b2c','#fb6a4a','#fc9272','#fcbba1','#fee0d2','#92c5de','#4393c3','#2166ac','#053061']
        cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(clist)
    # cticks = np.arange(-20,45,5)
    # norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(cticks, cmap.N, clip=True)
        
        bbox = [65,100,6.5,40]
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(f1.LONGITUDE, f1.LATITUDE)  # for rf_anom
        if h > 0: 
            bbox = [40,120,-10,40]                  
            ax.set_extent(bbox[h],crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
            X, Y = np.meshgrid(f2.lon, f2.lat)  

            iax=ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,var[h][i], cmap=cmap
                       # cmap = cmap.reversed(),
                      # norm = norm,
                      )
            ax.coastlines()
    cticks1 = np.arange(-20,50,10)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(iax,ax=ax,                  # 3 different colorbar 
                          location='right',
                          pad=0.05, 
                          drawedges=True,
                          shrink=0.8, 
                          fraction=0.04,
                          aspect=18,  
                          orientation= 'vertical',
                          extend='both',
                          # ticks=cticks1
                          )                  # colorbar settings
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=fs)
```

the following errors was  displayed while runnig the code.
`AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'add_feature', AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'gridlines', AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_extent'`

Answer (score 0):

Your axes are not `cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes`. It means that they don't have the `add_feature` method.

To create `GeoAxes`:

```py
# Set up a standard map for latlon data.
geo_axes = pyplot.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

# Set up an OSGB map.
geo_axes = pyplot.subplot(2, 2, 1, projection=cartopy.crs.OSGB())
```

from the [Cartopy documentation](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.14/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.add_feature)